# List of CSVs written inside Byte strings to be saved with individual Filenames

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list of data as byte strings and another list that consists of file names for that data. This data needs to be saved as individual CSV files based on the list of names. I don't know why, but Pandas `to_csv` isn't working for this particular task (probably has to do with the data inside the byte strings).

Basically, I have something like this:

```
filename: ['/Users/Coding Projects/Data/APIData/TEST.csv',
'/Users/Coding Projects/Data/APIData/Delivery New York.csv',
'/Users/Coding Projects/Data/APIData/Traffic 10.csv']
```

Which are all the file names, plus the location of the directory.
Note: This filename is generated by appending the directory name into the string, so basically:
`'/Users/Coding Projects/Data/APIData/' + 'TEST' + '.csv'` and so on..

And then large files of CSV files wrapped up in byte strings like this:
(this is just an example since I can't show a large file, I'll just show what it looks like).

```
All_reports_files: [b'Keep the addresses ready                  
Here is a list of data                  
John, Doe,120 jefferson st.,Riverside, NJ, 8075
Jack, McGinnis, 220 hobo Av., Phila, PA, 9119',

b'Keep the addresses ready                  
Here is a list of data                  
John "Da Man",Repici,120 Jefferson St.,Riverside,NJ,8075
Stephen Tyler,7452 Terrace "At the Plaza" road,SomeTown,SD,91234',

b'Name,"Sex","Age","Height(in)","Weight(lbs)"
Alex,"M",41,174,170
Bert,"M",42,168,166', 

'Report can not be Processed!',
 
b'Name,"Sex","Age","Height(in)","Weight(lbs)",
Dave,"M",39,172,167,
Elly,"F",30,166,124']
```

I want to download these files with their filenames accordingly, and then put them in a folder. So, my attempt to do this was:

I created a loop, which gets the files from the filename list, and then another nested loop that takes the reports from the reports, and write those reports with the file names accordingly.

```
for files in filenames:
    for reports in All_reports_files:
        if not reports == 'Report can not be Processed!':
            with open(files, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(reports)
```

For some reason this isn't working.

This code takes only the first report: `All_reports_files[0]` and saves it as individual files like `TEST.csv`, `Traffic 10.csv`, `Delivery New York.csv`.

So, all the 3 CSV files would only have the contents of the first report `All_reports_files[0]` in there. I don't know why it does that, but I want to save all the files with the individual filenames.

Comment: I am confused, " binary files which consists of csv data " seems to be contradictory. Can you please be specific about exactly what you mean by that?

Comment: Furthermore, ". The problem that I am facing is that this code only takes the very first file from the All_reports_files. and then saves it with different file names. So basically I get the first file downloaded multiple times, with different names. " isn't very clear either

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga
Thank you for pointing it out! I meant to say Byte strings not Binary files haha
Totally different things and I was confused.
I fixed it in the question for you and reworded the last part as well!
Let me know if there is anything else I can do!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a *nested* loop. The inner loop is iterating over the reports and is writing *each* report in the file from the outer loop. I.e. your code should write the *last* report in every available file (it does here). You could fix that by doing something like:

```py
valid_reports = (
    report for report in All_reports_files if report != 'Report can not be Processed!'
)
for filename, report in zip(filenames, valid_reports):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(report)
```

This loops *simultaneously* over filenames and valid reports. It stops when either all filenames are used or there are no more valid reports.